# ¿Cómo compartir datos entre procedimientos almacenados? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Me he encontrado con un pequeño inconveniente al utilizar datos entre varios procedimientos almacenados puesto que creé un SP el cual me ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado de un servidor distinto y me almacena sus resultados en una tabla temporal la cual despues utilizo en el mismo SP para hacer left join de esa tabla temporal a una de mis tablas de mi servidor, despues de terminar esta consulta creo otro nuevo SP para almacenar los resultados del SP anterior que acabe de mencionarles a otra tabla temporal pero al ejecutar este segundo SP me muestra el siguiente error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Cabe mencionar que el Sp el cual ejecuta el Sp de otro servidor y ese mismo necesitan de 4 parametros para poder ejecutarlo y mostrar los resultados.
Intente cambiar la tabla temporal por una tabla normal pero sigue el mismo error, ¿Como puedo resolver este problema? Espero puedan entender mi explicación puesto que los Sp son bastante largos para agregarlos como ejemplo.

Este es mi SP que ejecuta el Sp de otro servidor y el segundo que hice los cuales quiero que sus resultados se junten en una tabla:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TR_RepAxis
@UserID varchar(100),
@Report varchar(100),
@Setting varchar(100),
@dummy varchar(max) NULL
AS
BEGIN   
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE @res varchar(max)= NULL                 
            DECLARE @t TABLE (resultado VARCHAR(MAX))

            DECLARE @Fechainicio date
            set @Fechainicio = '01-01-2022'
            DECLARE @Fechafin date
            set @Fechafin = GETDATE()           
                    
            declare @curso varchar(max) 
            set @curso = (select Val from tblMatrices where ID=642)
            declare  @Idmatriz varchar(max) 
            set @Idmatriz = (select id from tblMatrices where ID=642)

            DECLARE @Incp varchar(max)              
            select @Incp = stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.WorkdayID as varchar(max))
            from tblIncapacidades t
            for xml path ('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
            );

            /*  Tabla temporal para almacenar los resultado de la lista de cursos   */
            CREATE TABLE #udvM12953_CoursesList (
            cur_clave varchar(max),
            cur_nombre varchar(max),
            fecha_valido_desde date,
            duracion int,
            RevisionID int,
            RevisionName varchar(100),
            tipo_empleado varchar(50)
            )
        
            /*  GUARDAR DUMMY Y REEMPLAZAR  */      
            BEGIN                       
                INSERT INTO @t 
                exec spu_SetUserSetting @UserID, @Report, @Setting, @dummy          
                SELECT @res=resultado FROM @t

            /*  MATRIZ PLASTICOS    */
            IF @Idmatriz = '642'                
                BEGIN           
                delete from Temp_Rep065
                INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065
                exec TR_AxisNA  @dummy

                INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065
                exec [Servidor].[basededatos].[dbo].[storeprocedure]
                @DateStart = @Fechainicio,--@dStart,
                @DateEnd = @Fechafin,--@dEnd,
                @cur_clave_str = @curso,
                @emp_clave_str = @dummy --emp_clave
                
                /*  Lista de Cursos */
                INSERT INTO #udvM12953_CoursesList
                exec [Servidor].[basededatos].[dbo].[udvM12953_CoursesList]                         


                select * from Temp_Rep065               
                    

                END
            END
END
GO
```

Este es mi segundo sp el cual me trae algunos registros los cuales son sacados por filtros de una tabla que tengo y que quiero insertar en la tabla como se muestra en el primer SP:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TR_AxisNA
@dummy varchar(max) null
as
BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            /*  Primera condicion para sacar los empleados que N/A al codigo MX-AG14-609    */
            delete from Temp_Rep065  /* LIMPIAR LA TABLA SI TIENE REGISTROS PREVIOS */
            create table #firtTable(
            workDayId varchar(50), 
            employeeName varchar(150), 
            jobPosition varchar(150), 
            Director varchar(100), 
            hireDate date) 

            ;WITH CTEPrueba AS(
            SELECT  workDayId, 
                    EmployeeName, 
                    CASE WHEN JobPosition IN( 'Student', 'Profesionista en Desarrollo', 'Prácticante')
                        THEN 'Student'
                        ELSE JobPosition END AS 'Job Position', 
                    Director,
                    hireDate
            FROM  dbo.TableHeadCount
            WHERE workDayId IN (SELECT value 
                                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dummy, ','))                             
            )
            INSERT INTO #firtTable (workDayId,employeeName,jobPosition,Director,hireDate)
            select * from CTEPrueba
            where [Job Position] in( 'Assembler', 'Shipping & Receiving Handler', 'Material Handler', 'Operations Coordinator', 'Customer Service Representative',
            'Program Administrator', 'Program Manager', 'Program Management Manager')
    

            declare @firstCond varchar(Max)
            select @firstCond = COALESCE(@firstCond+',' , '') + workDayId from #firtTable

            declare @curso1 varchar(100) = 'MX-AG14-609'

            insert into Temp_Rep065
            exec TR_CursosNA @firstCond, @curso1

            --SELECT * FROM Temp_Rep065u
END
GO
```

Les agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Si, no puedes hacer el INSERT EXEC de stored procedures anidados.
Ya intentaste, en el segundo Sp guardar la información en una tabla temporal global "##"?
ya con eso la puedes consumir después.

Comment: No agregues los SP's completos, pero puedes preparar un [mcve] que ejemplifique el problema.

Comment: @MrDonPh0x no necesita ser global. Una tabla temporal local puede funcionar perfectamente bien.

Comment: @LuisCazares ya intente con con tabla temporal, y una permanente(local) y aun asi me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje de error, ya agregue mis SP y a lo mejor estoy haciendo algo mal si es suficiente usando una tabla temporal

Comment: ya consideraste hacer los strored procedures como funciones tipo tabla?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x No, no lo habia considerado porque no se como realizarlo ya que no he trabajado con funciones